# How to get rid of `forKey` string literals in `UserDefaults` with Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm sick of repeating countless `coolFeatureEnabled` string literals while working with `UserDefaults`. If there a good way to get rid of them with Swift 3?

```
var coolFeatureEnabled: Bool {
    get { return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "coolFeatureEnabled") }
    set { UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "coolFeatureEnabled") }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to avoid string literals with `#function` in Swift 3

```
// a little bit of setup

private func getBool(key: String = #function) -> Bool {
    return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: key)
}

private func setBool(_ newValue: Bool, key: String = #function) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key)
}


// and here is the fun part

var coolFeatureEnabled: Bool {
    get { return getBool() }
    set { setBool(newValue) }
}

var anotherFeatureEnabled: Bool {
    get { return getBool() }
    set { setBool(newValue) }
}

...
```

Comment: @dan check it out, you'll be surprised ;-)

Comment: @dan are sure you're using Swift 3? default `#function` parameter expands to function name, which is either `coolFeatureEnabled` or `anotherFeatureEnabled`. you can easily check it by inserting `print(key);` to setter or getter

Comment: @dan It actually will work, as when used as a default parameter, `#function` [takes the name of the declaration in which the function is called](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID389) – in this example it will take the name `"coolFeatureEnabled"` or `"anotherFeatureEnabled"`.